# Making text field editable on button click

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am pretty much new to React so apologies for lack of code here.

Lets say I have a text field which shows the name of a user. When I click a button, I want this field to be editable.

Can this be done in ReactJS?

Comment: **YES** you can, just create a function that returns same object with `enabled=true` like     `render: function() { return <input type="text" enabled="true" value="" />; }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use like this,

ES6 js:

```
 class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state={disable:true,
               val:"username"}
  }
  handleClick(e){

 this.setState({disable:!this.state.disable})
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div className="wrapper">
        <input type="text" disabled={this.state.disable} value={this.state.val}/>
       <input type="button" value="Enable/Disable" onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Working [Jsbin](http://jsbin.com/wodetugisi/edit?html,js,console,output)